# Make a shortcut to Ubuntu bash.exe on Windows 10 that doesn't auto-close

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-shortcut

I would like to make a shortcut on Windows 10 that opens C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ([Ubuntu on Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about)), runs a command and doesn't close the terminal.

I made a shortcut with target to `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c free` and it runs the "free" command but closes the terminal right after running it. How to prevent it from closing?

Also what would be better: is there a way to load a bash script using such a shortcut (a set of commands located in a text file that such a shortcut would open and execute one after another) without closing the terminal after the execution? I suppose preventing the terminal from closing when running a "target" and a text file would be two separate methods?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a shortcut from the Application folder:

1. Access the Application folder by entering `explorer shell:AppsFolder` in Windows Command Prompt.
2. Right-click on Ubuntu or other applications -> Create shortcut
3. Click Yes on the msgbox saying the shortcut can be placed on the desktop.
4. Enjoy!

Comment: That "shell:AppsFolder" thing is great.  I've often *banged my head* in frustration with Windows "special" shortcut types, like the Ubuntu one is a "CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu2.0.0.4onWindows_"!!  Really MS?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `& pause` to the command line might work. I can't test it since I can't run the Linux tools for Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you, `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c free & pause` didn't work. But `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c free & bash` worked! And with `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c free & read` it also works but I can't type further commands.

Comment: `bash -c free & pause` won't work because `pause` is only run after bash has exited. `&` in Windows is not for running a command in background. `bash -c "free & pause"` doesn't work either because `pause` is not a bash command

Answer (score 0):

In this case since you didn't modify any environmental state, you can simply start another bash session like this

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "free; bash"
```

or maybe better

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "free; exec $SHELL"
```

If environment variables need to be changed then just write the commands in the rc_file and call bash with

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe --rcfile rc_file
```